# constructing a priority queue in java with reverse order in O(n) time

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

In Java, is there a simple way to create a PriorityQueue out of an unordered collection of numbers in O(n) time, but in reverse order? None of the constructors of PriorityQueue take in both a collection AND a comparator to specify ordering. I know you can create a PriorityQueue specifying a comparator, and then later call addAll to add all the unordered numbers. However, I think addAll would add each value individually as opposed to heapifying the unordered collection, so I don't think it would be O(n) time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the class leaves a number of ways open for optimization. Just like many other standard library classes.

Comment: The best option that I can think of is to first covert your collection into a `SortedSet` and then convert the `SortedSet` into a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: There'll only be anything in it, though, if you can pre-sort the elements in a way that performs better than O(n log n). Collections.sort(), for example, is essentially O(n log n).

Comment: You could maybe pre-sort in parallel, but it won't give you an order of magnitude speedup.

Comment: You may also want to look into alternate collection libraries. There is apache commons collections, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to first negate your numbers, then create a heap out of them in O(n). Later, you just need to remember to negate the numbers back after you retrieve them from the heap.

Answer (score -1):

addAll has O(n*log(n)) complexity, so that is not so terrible.

I don't know where you got the idea that creating a PriorityQueue out of unordered collection of numbers has O(n), I think it is the same as for addAll.

Comment: You can build a heap from an unordered list in O(n). See http://cs.utsa.edu/~dj/cs3343/lecture6.html

Comment: That is an in-place algorithm, it does not apply if you have to copy elements from one collection to another.

Comment: Copying a list of n into an array can be done in O(n). And, one can build a heap from an array in O(n).

Comment: That is all nice in theory, but in practice PriorityQueue contructors actually use addAll function.

http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/PriorityQueue-source.html

Comment: A good implementation constructs the heap in O(n), e.g., http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#PriorityQueue.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: As a side note, bulk-loading a heap in O(n) is as easy as incremental loading. You just start from the end. It works very well in practice. With a bit of effort, you can also do bulk-repairs, which would then allow any `addAll` to do this. I wish someone would submit a patch to OpenJDK that at least exploits this whenver `addAll` is called on an *empty* queue: add all elements without repairing the heap, then bulk-repair it.

Comment: @cohadar -- that's not strictly true. Provided you pass in some object that implements SortedSet, the PriorityQueue will fetch and add the data 'directly' via the passed-in object's toArray() method.

Comment: Lets stick to the practicality people.
He said he used "unordered collection" so SortedSet is not his option.
And OpenJDK is all nice with it's cool heapify implementation, but is someone really suggesting that you should solve a code problem by installing an alternative JDK?

Comment: @cohadar - Presumably the point is he's prepared to order the collection in whatever way is fastest and then persuade the PriorityQueue to take that data as "raw, pre-sorted". The SortedSet wrapper is just that-- a wrapper to "fool" the API into taking the data as pre-sorted. I also, agree that in practice, it probably won't be worth it. I was essentially contending your point that PriorityQueue constructors always use the addAll function.